# Service worker fetch event: Why no infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

This is about some behaviour while handling the `fetch` event inside a **service worker**.

When, inside `fetch` event handler, `fetch()` is called, the `fetch` event doesn't seem to get triggered again. This is actually good but I still wonder why that doesn't happen.

I've looked at code at https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/caching-files-with-service-worker#on_network_response which goes like:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.open('mysite-dynamic').then(function(cache) {
      return cache.match(event.request).then(function (response) {
        return response || fetch(event.request).then(function(response) {
          cache.put(event.request, response.clone());
          return response;
        });
      });
    })
  );
});
```

I've tried that code myself and the call to `fetch()` (right after the `||`) **is** executed but doesn't trigger the event handler again. Why not? Also some link to a page explaining this would be appreciated.

Comment: …because that's how `fetch` in service workers works?

Comment: @Bergi Indeed, it seems so but I couldn't find any documentation about that e.g. on MDN. Maybe I need to go and read the spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, performing a `fetch()` from inside a service worker (i.e. when the global object is `ServiceWorkerGlobalScope`) will never trigger a `fetch` handler.

The mechanism that determines this behavior comes from the [Fetch specification](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#fetch-method), section 5.6, describing `fetch()`, step 5:

> If request’s client’s global object is a ServiceWorkerGlobalScope object, then set request’s [service-workers mode](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#request-service-workers-mode) to "none".

There are a bunch of other scenarios in the [Service Worker specification](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/) that also describe when service-workers mode is set to "none", like when performing a network request as part of `importScripts()`

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for.